# RDD with recursive union in scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, rdd

This question was posted in the forum before but I do not see an answer. I am relatively new to scala and I understand that recursive methods in scala needs type.

Let us say, `var matrix_input` is of type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Long, Double)]`

If I do a recursive RDD union as,

```
var matrix_input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Long, Double)] =
  matrix_input.union(matrix_input)
```

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Why is this happening when `matrix_input.collect()` clearly shows following output.

```
Array[(Long, Long, Double)] = Array((0,0,-1.0), (0,1,-1.0))
```

Comment: You get `NullPointerException` only because you use REPL. Otherwise it would during compilation because `matrix_input` is already defined. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you mean something like this: `var matrix_input: RDD[(Long, Long, Double)] = ???;  matrix_input = matrix_input.union(matrix_input)`?

Comment: I have to agree with zero323, the code above is not sensible because `var` as shown is for assigning initial values. Updates would normally occur on a separate line of code.  Is your question about why this one bad line of code won't work, or about how to do a self-union?

Comment: can you post complete code, just to see and debug.?

Comment: Thanks zero33, Paul, Srini. I was just trying to declare, assign and update a variable in same line of code. Seems erroneous and not a smart thing to do. It works when I put them in separate lines.  Thanks again!